# How to send Delivery Receipts using PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send emails and i want to be able to send Delivery Receipts to the sender

I have tried:

```
$email->ConfirmReadingTo = "sender@domain.com";
```

which sends a Read Reciept to the sender

i have tried using the below code to send a Delivery Receipt but it doesn't work - i think it is meant for sending *Read Receipts *

```
Disposition-Notification-To:
```

but this is sending a Read Receipt and not a Delivery Receipt

how can i also send Delivery Receipts using PHPMailer?